# Does the Sound Blaster Live! Value had hardware support for Adlib/OPL3?

Tags: ibm-pc, sound, audio, digital-audio, soundblaster

As I m buying a computer without an onboard sound card, I m thinking about using my old Creative Sound card from 21 years ago and buying a pcie riser adapter instead of a modern sound card (I m interested in one with hardware fm synthesis support rather than one emulated through pcm and sampling).
**Please note in that case that it s not only about hardware accelaration and is also about sound quality because of not using pcm sound at all.**

I know that by 1995, Creative abonned fm synthesis and started to use a low quality compatible hardware alternative based on cqm synthesis in order to cut down costs in their pci version of Sound Blaster 16 cards. But as processing powered evolved, cost to include it again should have decreased which doesn t means later models like mine don t include it.

I also know Creative provided a tsr in order to let dos programs perform sound synthesis (I lost the driver CD).
**But I fail to understand if it was for emulating everything or just reroute irq for accessing the hardware?**

**Also, if yes does they use fm synth or still use their low quality cqm based alternative?**

Back in 2006, I was too young to pay attention about this in Windows 98se hardware settings and as Windows doesn t support hardware synthesis since Windows Vista and Linux never had support for such things with pci card, this is something I ve no idea on how to figure.

Comment: The only sign I m having is the organ sounded very different  than in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h7sDBa8bHos) where it s emulated.

Comment: Although Ross' answer is uniformly true as far as I know, there are lots of revisions of cards under a single Sound Blaster range name. Can you give us the CTxxxx or SBxxxx number given on your card?

Comment: @knol as I said it s the Value version. For the exact détails I left the card to the local repair shop in order to let them find an adapter. There are lot of pci to pcie adapters. But my computer won t have plain pcie hardware ports. Only riser pcie ports which is for plugging cables instead of cards. **As I m failing to find a pcie riser to pci cable supportting dma** I had to leave the card to someone more experienced at finding hardware.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the Soundblaster Live! doesn't have any hardware support for FM synthesis.  Soundblaster 16 emulation is provided by trapping accesses to the Soundblaster and AdLib ports and then emulating their functionality in software.  There is no OPL or CQM chip, or even a Soundblaster PCM compatible chip.

Note that in the MS-DOS and Windows VxD drivers this emulation is based on generating PCI #SERR errors, which get turned into NMIs by the chipset.  However this doesn't work on newer motherboards, basically Pentium 4 or newer because by the time the NMI has arrived at the CPU, the CPU has gone on to execute the next instruction causing that one to appear to have accessed the SoundBlaster or AdLib port.

Comment: Back in 2006 (the last time I used the card), I can definitely tell you that dos games running in Windows 98se that required opl3 worked with my 4.2Ghz Prescott cpu.

Comment: @user2284570 That's because the Windows drivers included SB16 emulation.  You might have been using the WDM drivers which have their own separate SB16 emulator, which didn't rely on #SERR and NMIs, instead using Virtual 8086 mode I/O trapping.  What Creative should've done for their own emulator.

Comment: I didn t used the vxd driver so it couldn t affect dos.

Comment: @user2284570 See my updated comment.  Both the VxD and WDM drivers included SB16 software emulation.

Comment: Actually changing sound settings in the autoexec.bat did make this game silent https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h7sDBa8bHos. If I recall correctly, wdm drivers only worked for nt based programs. Not dos.

Comment: Also, what the vxd driver did which the dos driver couldn t? 98se dos programs runs almost in real cooperative mode (just using vm86 addressing but the cpu could be reconfigured to access the full ram).

Answer (score 1):

The SB Live series did not include any legacy hardware and support for these were made available with emulation only.

Comment: Source? Or did you try the tsr with a plain ac97 card?

Comment: @user2284570 The TSR won't work with a plain AC97 card.  It requires a Soundblaster Live! to work.

Comment: @RossRidge the tsr should had used pcm capabilities of the card. Anything compatible should work (maybe the emutek if not the ac97).

Comment: @user2284570 No, it doesn't work like that.

Comment: @RossRidge then, did it use things like the dsp? What it did beside sending pcm to dac?

Comment: Well, I have had a SB Live card at some point. And Wikipedia actually has the same info. Only a handful of PCI sound chips had real OPL hardware, such as Forte Media FM801 and some Yamaha PCI sound chips.

Comment: @Justme nice. Do you still have a copy of the install CD with that tsr as this is something which would help me as I lost it? Wikipedia doesn t have the same info. Real hardware midi used pcm wavetables. The point is having them in system ram rather than in a dedicated rom. It definitely did had hardware midi.

Comment: @user2284570 I don't recall if I had the CD, but if I had, it went along with the card. But now you are talking about MIDI and PCM wavetables, that has nothing to do with OPL3, which basically uses a 256-entry log-sin waveform table that is well known by now, thanks to various reverse-engineering efforts including me.

Comment: @Justme that s related to the wikipedia statement you refer. I don t see the point of emulating mpu401 for dos if their were hardware midi. So it says nothing to opl3. Also your re correct about sine, this is why I m interested in actual hardware and not pcm emulation or fpga.

Comment: @user2284570 You would have to emulate a MPU401 interface to get MIDI data from a game that only knows how to play to an MPU401 MIDI device, otherwise there would not be MIDI music. And then the TSR would command the sound card to play PCM waveform samples based on MIDI data. These days the OPL3 should be quite well reverse engineered, the person who wrote Nuked OPL could even further refine the already reverse-engineered algorithms from looking at silicon die photos. The FPGA emulation happened before that, so it may not be as perfect as Nuked is.

Comment: @Justme I rather think the best option is to catch the isa irq and rewrite the commands for the modern hardware midi synthesizer. Even then, there s no pcie sound card able to work as fpga. And I m not even talking about 64 bits wdm sound drivers. And as I said, I m very septical about the difference between generating things like sine or half sine using digital only hardware without analog components (I m meaning fpga) and pcm emulation.

Comment: @user2284570 But OPL chips are not analog components. They generate audio completely digitally, until the digital audio stream is fed to a separate DAC, which converts the digital data into analog audio.

Comment: @Justme correct. Which doesn t means they use analog for some génération part internnally.

Comment: @user2284570 Highly unlikely. Yamaha licensed Chowning's FM synthesis technology as they realized it allowed fully digital audio synthesis to get rid of any analogue imperfections. First successful fully digital FM synthesizer (before the DAC that is) was the DX7 in 1983 and the later chips such as the OPL series have their roots there. If there was something analogue inside the OPL, other than the transistors implementing the digital logic, we'd surely know by now. If you do know something based on actually reverse engineering the chip, please share your findings.

Comment: @Justme find. do you know an fpga with a 64 bits wdm driver implementation?

Comment: @user2284570 That's not how FPGAs work. They do what they are programmed to do. If you replicate an existing card into an FPGA implementation, then you can use the drivers of the existing card, as the driver would not know the difference between a real card and FPGA implementation of a real card. If you program the FPGA to be something else that does not exist yet, you need to write drivers for it yourself as they do not exist yet.

Comment: @Justme correct. It depends what the card does implement. If it s just plain opl3 (there s no wdm driver for it) then the answer is no. But if it s full sound blaster 16 then the answer is yes. As far I m aware, I never heard an fpga able to perform dac by itself along an audio jack plug. So with a custom implementation must come dedicated drivers (even if it s for sending everything to a port the dos way).